# Automatically name output of montage based on input files

Tags: imagemagick, bash-scripting, montage

I have a folder with images separated into channels:

```
IMAGE_A_R.jpg
IMAGE_A_G.jpg
IMAGE_A_B.jpg
IMAGE_A_RGB.jpg
IMAGE_A1_R.jpg
IMAGE_A1_G.jpg
IMAGE_A1_B.jpg
IMAGE_A1_RGB.jpg
IMAGE_B_R.jpg
IMAGE_B_G.jpg
IMAGE_B_B.jpg
IMAGE_B_RGB.jpg
```

What I'm doing now is making 4x1 pictures using montage and naming then "OUTPUT_%d.jpg". This however forces me to manually rename them into e.g. "IMAGE_A.jpg" afterwards, which for this large image collection is very time consuming.

What I'd like to do is to automatically, from the list above create 4x1 montages named:

```
IMAGE_A.jpg
IMAGE_A1.jpg
IMAGE_B.jpg
```

Ideally, I'd like to automatically combine all "IMAGE_A" into a 4x montage, all "IMAGE_B" into another and so on. Each IMAGE_[letter] can have from 1-4 numbers so it's not possible to simply make for example a 4x2 montage.

I've tried using %[name] and %f with no luck and haven't found anything helpful in the ImageMagick manual or in my google searches.

I suspect that to do this I'd have to use some BASH-script, but I fear I have to little knowledge to do that without help.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, collect the list of image names:

```
ls *jpg | gawk -F_ '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Now, pass them through `montage`:

```
ls *jpg | gawk -F_ '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | 
 while read n; do montage *\_$n\_* IMAGE_$n.jpg; done
```

This assumes your file names contain no spaces or other strange characters. I'm not sure about your "ideal" case. If you update you question to show your "ideal" output, I should be able to work something out for you.

---

**Update:**

This I wrote a tiny Perl script should do what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my %k;             ## declare the hash that will store the image names
while(<>){         ## loop through STDIN
    chomp;         ## remove newline (\n)
    @a=split(/_/); ## split the line on '_' and save as array @a

    ###################################################
    # Since the image names can have varying numbers  #
    # of "_", we want to use the penultimate item in  #
    # the array ($a[$#a-1]) as the image name prefix  #
    ###################################################
    $a[$#a-1]=~s/\d*//g;

    #############################################################
    # Now that we have the prefix ('A' or 'B' in your example), #
    # we will save this image name in the hash of that prefix   #
    #############################################################
    $k{$a[$#a-1]}{$_}=1;
}
## The keys of the hash '%k' are all the prefixes we have found
foreach my $prefix (keys(%k)){
    @images=keys(%{$k{$prefix}});   ## all the images with this prefix

    ## Print the montage command to be executed (testing)
    print "montage @images -title $prefix -tile 4x $prefix.jpg\n";

    ##############################################################
    # If the commands printed above are correct, uncomment this  #
    # line to execute them instead of only printing.             #
    ##############################################################
    #`montage @images -title $prefix -tile 4x $prefix.jpg`
}
```

You can either save it as `foo.pl` or whatever you prefer and run it like this:

```
ls *jpg | perl foo.pl
```

Or you can run it as a one liner:

```
ls *jpg | perl -e 'my %k; while(<>){chomp; @a=split(/_/); $a[$#a-1]=~s/\d*//g; $k{$a[$#a-1]}{$_}=1;} foreach my $prefix (keys(%k)){@images=keys(%{$k{$prefix}}); `montage @images -title $prefix -tile 4x $prefix.jpg`;}'
```

**IMPORTANT**: This script is very simple and will not work if your file names contain spaces or other strange characters. I am assuming that this is not a problem for you, it is relatively easy to fix but makes the syntax more complex all around.

Comment: The ideal case would be:

Files are named `[name]-[letter][number]-[channel].jpg`, where `[number]` isn't present on all images (the letter-only image being an overview). Ideally all images with the same `[name]` and `[letter]` should be in the same montage, each image labeled with `[channel]`, the montage having a header being `[name]` and the file named `[name]-[letter].jpg`

Comment: From what I can see, the command you posted only looks at the `[letter][number]` ending. Since are the same for all `[name]`, that will not work perfectly. If needed, I could easily change the naming of the files to so that all have `[number]`.

Comment: Thanks to your script above, with slight modifications, I managed to almost do what I want:

    `ls *jpg | gawk -F_ '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | 
    while read n; do montage $n\_* -title $n -tile 4x $n.jpg; done;`

However, I can't figure out how to separate them based on only the letter (see above). Nor can I figure out how to fetch the channel name. Now, this is of lesser importance - and while I'd love to know how to do this - you've already helped me enough. **Thanks!**

Comment: @Morgan you're very welcome, I am still not entirely clear on what you want. Could you give a detailed example? Do you want all `A`, `A1`, `A2` etc images in the same file? Some simple scripting should be able to do what you need. Also, the `ls *jpg` in your previous comment is useless if you are also doing `ls *HeLa*`.

Comment: Exactly all `A#` should be in the same montage, all `B#` should be in the same and so on. What I would need is to take all images that has the same name, for example `NAME-A#` and make a montage of them, the same for `NAME-B#` and so on. The closest I've come is to do `gawk -F_ { OFS = "_" } { print $1, $2}'`, but I don't know how to get rid of the number. Since some of the files have more `_` in them, I also wonder if it's possible to do the counting from behind, since the `A#`, `B#` and so on always comes before `_[CHANNEL]`.

Comment: @Morgan see updated answer, the script should work for you.